# rake db:create giving me "... (at master) is not checked out", run bundle install

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, bundler

I'm seriously stumped.  I run bundle install successfully:

```
bundle install

...
Using activerecord-oracle_enhanced-adapter (1.4.1) from git://github.com/rsim/oracle-enhanced.git (at master)
...
Your bundle is complete! Use `bundle show [gemname]` to see where a bundled gem is installed.
```

But, when I run rake db:create, I get the following

```
vagrant@lucid32:/vagrant$ rake db:create
(in /vagrant)
git://github.com/rsim/oracle-enhanced.git (at master) is not checked out. Please run `bundle install`
```

Trying this too:

```
vagrant@lucid32:/vagrant$ bundle exec db:create
bundler: command not found: db:create
Install missing gem executables with `bundle install`
```

In my Gemfile:

```
gem 'activerecord-oracle_enhanced-adapter', '~>1.4.1', :git => 'git://github.com/rsim/oracle-enhanced.git'
```

This is on Ubuntu, where ruby 1.8.7 was installed.  I'm running 1.9.2p290 w/ rbenv.

Comment: Try `bundle exec rake db:create`?

Comment: It should be `bundle exec rake db:create`, not `bundle exec db:create`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You meant to use `bundle exec rake db:create`.

Answer (score 0):

See if this helps https://github.com/carlhuda/bundler/blob/master/ISSUES.md